# Pass Custom Variable to PayPal server via IPN Message and Response

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator, paypal-sandbox, paypal-soap

I had successfully integrated Paypal with my iPhone application, but I got stuck over passing the Custom variable via SOAP to Pay pal using IPN Message.

Has anyone pass the Custom Variable to Pay-pal Server????I am making an application for a restaurant,user can make payment using Pay-pal server.

I need to pass the Custom variable (i.e Bucket Id) to Paypal. I get this Bucket Id via web service which I call before making request to pay pal server. Now I need to pass this Bucket Id as Custom Variable to Paypal Server so that it returns the Message Notification.

Note: - I need to make payment using this Bucket Id.

At last when I will get this Notification , I will again call web-service which is going to update the server database of client.

I used this reference:
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf

Any kind of help is welcomed.....

Please suggest me with some sample code as I had googled alot about this or other reference....

Comment: Hi, Ajay. I have the same problem, but with android application. Have you solved this issue? If yes, answer please how did you do that? Thanks.

Comment: @yozhik ... Nopes just dropped that idea & proceeded wiht the simple payment.Since that was making things complicated. But certainly refer to DOc link with the question, it would help you with IPN which is that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I find out the solution. But for Android, but I think it can be applied to iOS:

```
PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();
         payment.setCurrencyType("USD");
         payment.setSubtotal(3.30);
         payment.setRecipient("test_seller11@gmail.com");

         payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);
         payment.setCustomID("7982");
        payment.setIpnUrl("some.site.com/PaymentCallback");
        payment.setDescription("Buy 300 coins");
```

So this is the solution, to pass your extra params to IPN, and to get them back in callback on your server:

```
payment.setCustomID("7982");
```

Comment: this is not working, can you help in sending a unique id with paypal json

Comment: Sorry, but I can't, it was in 4 years ago)