# send data to IPN Paypal from PayPalAndroidSDK

Tags: android, paypal

I'm trying to send a data or info additional from PayPalAndroidSDK to IPN, but I have not found the function, in this question [Pass Custom Variable to PayPal server via IPN Message and Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942305/pass-custom-variable-to-paypal-server-via-ipn-message-and-response), says that using setDescription(string), but this does not appear.

you know how to send additional info or what function use?

Tutorial said:

```
PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("8.75"), "USD", "hipster jeans");

Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, "credential-from-developer.paypal.com");
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID, "<someuser@somedomain.com>");

intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, "<YOUR_PAYPAL_EMAIL_ADDRESS>");
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);

startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass data to IPN. IPN pushes data to you (which would be a very difficult thing to do over mobile).

Comment: is better use MPL?, I like to know, if the sale status change

Comment: You'll need a server to relay the data for you, because IPN needs a fixed address to reach you.

Comment: Yes, but by this method PayPal does not send something that tell you bought, for example, does not tell if you bought a sweater or pants

Comment: IPN tells you what they bought if you passed that data into PayPal

Comment: MPL if you send personalized info, is not very beatiful but this work